# How to add mail input to form dynamicaly with Python Flask?

Tags: python, forms, flask

I'm trying to create an event with a guest in a form, but the guest number is not fixed, so I need to add an input field to my form dynamically.

I've made it in the past in Symfony with JavaScript, but I don't know if there is a special way to do this in Flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That needs to be done in js.

```
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
document.getElementById('your_form').appendChild(x);
```

That should be included in the event you want that to happen. I am not sure if i got correctly what you asked.

Comment: Well it does answer what I want to do thanks =) 
I wondered if it there was a more "flask" way to do it ahah